# Change location of error message using verify.JS

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've got a form with JS validation (verify.js) where phone OR email is required.  Everything is functional, my only issue is trying to change WHERE the validation error message appears.

[Here's a JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/R4t84/119/)

The `data-validate` attribute is what fires the verify.js rules.  I've written a rule `phoneOrEmail` that fires when the submit button is clicked.  This causes validation message to "attach" to the submit button.  I would like the validation message to appear near the phone or email fields.

My JS isn't very strong, so I'm hoping this is something simple.  [If it helps, here's the documentation for verify.js](http://verifyjs.com).

If you don't want to click through to the JSFiddle, here's my HTML:

```
<form action="#" method="post" name="landing_form" id="landing_form">
    <label for="phone">Phone Number</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="phone" id="phone" data-validate="min(10)">
    <label for="email">Email</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="email" id="email" data-validate="email">
    <input type="submit" value="Send Message" data-validate="phoneOrEmail">
</form>
```

And my JS:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $.verify.addRules({
        phoneOrEmail: function(r) {
            var phone = $('#phone').val();
            var email = $('#email').val();
            if (phone == '' && email == '') {
                return "Please supply phone OR email";
            } else {
                return true;
            }
        },
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I have added a span tag to your HTML o you can do it in this way:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
            $.verify.addRules({
                phoneOrEmail: function(r) {
                    var phone = $('#phone').val();
                    var email = $('#email').val();
                    if (phone == '' && email == '') {
                        $('.errMsg').html("Please supply phone OR email";)

                    } else {
                        return true;
                    }
                },
            });
        });
```

You can also do the same but for each 'email and Phone'.